# openSeadragon selection

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

Adding the selection plugin to my OpenSeadragon project, which already goes well with the basic functions, I did initiated it, but the something goes wrong with changing the size of selected area.
is shows up like this:-

[image]

Here are what i did to initiate it.

```js
var openSeadragon, selection;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      openSeadragon = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "openSeadragon1", 
        prefixUrl: "images/",
        tileSources: [],
        sequenceMode: true, 
        showReferenceStrip: true, 
        visibilityRatio: 0.2, 
        constrainDuringPan: true, 
        defaultZoomLevel: 0.8,
        minZoomLevel: 0.3, 
        maxZoomLevel: 10, 
        showNavigator: true, 
        nextButton: "next", 
        previousButton: "previous",
        minZoomImageRatio: 0.1, //of viewer size
        crossOriginPolicy: 'Anonymous',
      });
      selection = openSeadragon.selection({
        onSelection: function(rect) {
          alert(rect + ' Center point: ' + rect.getCenter() + ' Degree rotation: ' + rect.getDegreeRotation());
        }
      });
```

How to solve it?

Comment: There is no image in this code. Nothing in tileSources. The plugin probably can't calculate the size.

Comment: not exactly, I've add a button for users to add image(that part is not posted there.) @Peter Petrov